# Android 4.4 is coming - should I update my app?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Now that Android 4.4 is almost released, I have a question. Does it make sense to build my app against the new version of API and release the updated version to the market? Or does it make sense only if I want to use any of the new features? What is the best practice or the recommended approach?

Comment: As long as your app works, there is no need to build your app again.

Comment: @rcs Thanks. But what does it give me to build against the new API?

Comment: I don't think it gives any advantage to build against the new API. But you may want to consider Alecio's answer if you are building such app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like for any new Android version, you need to stay tuned to Google announcements, like the one that Alécio mentioned, as certain APIs could be deprecated/changed (in the case of KitKat, if your application depends on intercepting/reading/storing SMS messages, then you should read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)). You also need to figure out whether you want to take advantage of any new API to make your application better in one way or another. It's also possible that a whole new feature could be introduced, one that could be interesting to your application. Just use your common sense.

Finally, to be able to use the latest version, you just need to download the latest SDK and ADT, and increment the `targetSDKVersion` number against the latest API level (this is a general good practice). The list of API levels, for each Android version, are available [here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

Comment: Actually, I think everyone should always try to update their app, to make sure it will work on its best way on newer versions of Android. Google always adds new stuff to ADT , adds Lint warnings, fixes bugs, and allows to check if old functions are used where new ones can replace them. In order to update, you need to increase the targetSDKVersion to 19 and also update the project.properties file too. Then, you need to run Lint and look for important warnings and errors it finds. There are already new guidelines to prepare the app for the new version. even a tip to create an XXXHDPI app icon...

Comment: Another reason to update the app is to show users you care and show that your app is always new and refreshed.

Comment: An example from the past is what has happened with the change between Gingerbread and Honeycomb/ICS, where the action bar was introduced instead of the menu button. Apps that weren't updated to target the latest version got this annoying huge menu bar at the bottom, as shown on HTC One X devices : http://www.androidcentral.com/htc-one-x-shows-us-why-developers-need-lose-menu-button

Comment: This is all well said.

Comment: Yes, I wish I could write it as a new answer instead of a comment but for some reason this thread is closed.

Comment: You should consider writing a blog post then, I will be happy to point to it in my answer.

Comment: I don't have a blog, and I prefer not to have one, at least not for the near future.

Answer (score 2):

You should not worry about it. But if your app is a SMS app, then you might have to. Check out this article: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Answer (score 1):

Yeah..Earlier,you released your application with maximum sdk level is 17 above means, you don't have any problem with latest version..else,You released by 2.3 to 4.1 version means..You,should update your application also.Because APIs are different for above 4.1 and below 4.1. If required you need to update the latest APIs for Latest android version

Comment: What is the difference between 4.1 and below 4.1 you're talking about?

Comment: APIs are different..For example You have create one widget for enabling Data connection with version 4.0..Now,you have to use that Application into higher version which means 4.2 like that..That time you must get force close because,API level is different..Build in API also different.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to make any change to your app in order to make it work on the newest version of android unless you use in your code deprecated classes or methods.